# Scala: How to "map" an Array[Int] to a Map[String, Int] using the "map" method?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following `Array[Int]`: `val array = Array(1, 2, 3)`, for which I have the following mapping relation between an Int and a String:

```
val a1 = array.map{
  case 1 => "A"
  case 2 => "B"
  case 3 => "C"
}
```

To create a `Map` to contain the above mapping relation, I am aware that I can use a `foldLeft` method:

```
val a2 = array.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]()) { (m, e) =>
  m + (e match {
    case 1 => ("A", 1)
    case 2 => "B" -> 2
    case 3 => "C" -> 3
  })
}
```

which outputs:

> a2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(A -> 1, B -> 2, C
>   -> 3)

This is the result I want. **But can I achieve the same result via the `map` method?**

The following codes do not work:

```
val a3 = array.map[(String, Int), Map[String, Int]] {
  case 1 => ("A", 1)
  case 2 => ("B", 2)
  case 3 => ("C", 3)
}
```

The signature of `map` is

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)
(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

What is this `CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]`? I tried to read [Tribulations of CanBuildFrom](http://scala-lang.org/blog/2017/05/30/tribulations-canbuildfrom.html) but don't really understand it. That article mentioned Scala 2.12+ has provided two implementations for `map`. But how come I didn't find it when I use Scala 2.12.4?

I mostly use Scala 2.11.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll first define your function here for the sake of brevity in later explanation:

```
// worth noting that this function is effectively partial
// i.e. will throw a `MatchError` if n is not in (1, 2, 3)
def toPairs(n: Int): (String, Int) =
  n match {
    case 1 => "a" -> 1
    case 2 => "b" -> 2
    case 3 => "c" -> 3
  }
```

One possible way to go (as already highlighted in another answer) is to use `toMap`, which only works on collection of pairs:

```
val ns = Array(1, 2, 3)

ns.toMap // doesn't compile

ns.map(toPairs).toMap // does what you want
```

It is worth noting however that unless you are working with a lazy representation (like an `Iterator` or a `Stream`) this will result in two passes over the collection and the creation of unnecessary intermediate collections: the first time by mapping `toPairs` over the collection and then by turning the whole collection from a collection of pairs to a `Map` (with `toMap`).

You can see it clearly in [the implementation of `toMap`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L308-L314).

As suggested in the read you already linked in the answer (and in particular [here](https://scala-lang.org/blog/2017/05/30/tribulations-canbuildfrom.html#breakout-escape-hatch)) You can avoid this double pass in two ways:

- you can leverage `scala.collection.breakOut`, an implementation of `CanBuildFrom` that you can give `map` (among others) to change the target collection, provided that you explicitly provide a type hint for the compiler:

---

```
val resultMap: Map[String, Int] = ns.map(toPairs)(collection.breakOut)
val resultSet: Set[(String, Int)] = ns.map(toPairs)(collection.breakOut)
```

---

- otherwise, you can create a view over your collection, which puts it in the lazy wrapper that you need for the operation to not result in a double pass

---

```
ns.view.map(toPairs).toMap
```

---

You can read more about implicit builder providers and views in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336730/scala-how-to-map-an-arrayint-to-a-mapstring-int-using-the-map-method).

Answer (score 3):

Call `toMap` in the end of your expression:

```
val a3 = array.map {
  case 1 => ("A", 1)
  case 2 => ("B", 2)
  case 3 => ("C", 3)
}.toMap
```

Comment: This does not work. I still got the same errors: 
`Error:(36, 126) Cannot construct a collection of type Map[String,Int] with elements of type (String, Int) based on a collection of type Array[Int].
def get$$instance$$a3 = a3;/* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */ lazy val a3 = array.map[(String, Int), Map[String, Int]] {
                                                                                                                            ^`

Comment: And `Error:(36, 126) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Array[Int],(String, Int),Map[String,Int]])Map[String,Int].
Unspecified value parameter bf.
def get$$instance$$a3 = a3;/* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */ lazy val a3 = array.map[(String, Int), Map[String, Int]] {
                                                                                                                            ^`

Answer (score 2):

Basically `toMap` (credits to [Sergey Lagutin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48336745/2735286)) is the right answer.

You could actually make the code a bit more compact though:

```
val a1 = array.map { i => ((i + 64).toChar, i) }.toMap
```

If you run this code:

```
val array = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 0)
val a1 = array.map { i => ((i + 64).toChar, i) }.toMap
println(a1)
```

You will see this on the console:

```
Map(E -> 5, J -> 10, F -> 6, A -> 1, @ -> 0, G -> 7, L -> 12, B -> 2, C -> 3, H -> 8, K -> 11, D -> 4)
```